# Intent data is lost in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Yeah, I know that is so simple to pass data with an intent but suddendly not works. Extra data is always null.

Someone can tell me why... because I can't see any error.

I can debug the code, and when is in `startActivity(intent)` I can see the intent has extra data set correctly. When I stop the code in `getIntent().getExtras()` data extra is lost

Activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true);
intent.putExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.ARG_ARTICLE, article);
intent.putExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.IS_GEO_NOTIFICATION, isGeoNotification);

mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

`ScreenActivity.class` ( get in onCreate method)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
pushNotificationProductId = intent.getBooleanExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
isGeoNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.IS_GEO_NOTIFICATION, false);
mArticle = intent.getParcelable(ArgumentsNamesConfig.ARG_ARTICLE);
```

Comment: try this:- 
pushNotificationProductId = getIntent().getExtras().get(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION).toString();

Comment: By the way, is it just to confusse people you name a Bundle intent?

Comment: see my edit question, please

Comment: You mean all your getExtra return null?

Comment: intent.putExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true); is boolean and u are trying to get it as STRING(intent.getStringExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);) please correct it

Comment: Yes, sure @Prags but is not the problem, because intent haven't any data

Comment: can u chk this by 'intent.hasExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION)'  for every then u try to get values

Comment: yeah, nothing. Null If I do intent.getExtras() no extras

Comment: Are you sure you are using intent.getExtras() because in your code you are getting data using intent.getStringExtra() or intent.getBooleanExtra(). Sometimes getStringExtra() returns null. So try with intent.getExtras().get("Your key").toString()

Comment: No. I'm close to see the problem. My object have another objects inside. If I remove one of them, I can get all the extras. Could be because this object is so bigger??

Comment: can you place that part of code along with a bit more detail

Comment: You probably have incompatible parcel and unparcel methods for one or more of the objects that you have added as "extras". Double check the implementation of the parcel and unparcel methods and ensure that they read/write the exact same types in the exact same order.

Comment: can you check this answer, might it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392434/startactivityintent-is-doing-nothing

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, true); is boolean and u are trying to get it as STRING(intent.getStringExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION)

try changing tour code to this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    pushNotificationProductId = intent.getBooleanExtra(ArgumentsNamesConfig.IS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
    isGeoNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.IS_GEO_NOTIFICATION, false);
    mArticle = intent.getParcelable(ArgumentsNamesConfig.ARG_ARTICLE);
```

Comment: If I put Intent intent = getIntent().getExtras(); I get this erro Required:
android.content.Intent
Found:
android.os.Bundle

Comment: yep, but if I stop the debugger in pushNotificationProductId and I check the intent extra data is empty