# startActivity(intent) is doing nothing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcel

I'm trying to start an activity with a switch statement like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String key = "1010";
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add:
                //working
                break;
            case R.id.rotate_right:
                //working
                break;
            case R.id.fullscreen: //not working
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), fullScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(key, bitmap);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the next activity's code

```
public class fullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Intent starter = getIntent();
        bitmap = starter.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.key);
    }
}
```

I also added the second activity to the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".fullScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Here's R.menu.items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/add_item"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/rotate_right"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rotate_right_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/rotate_item"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/fullscreen_item"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

</menu>
```

It does nothing, so what can be the problem?

Note that just the fullscreen item is not working, so I think the problem is in the startActivity code.

Comment: Where is that `switch`? What are you doing to call it? Are you certain you have the correct `R.id` there? What exactly do you mean by "It does nothing"? Does the next `Activity` just not open? Is there any visual feedback when you click whichever, presumably, menu item that is?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post for more details @MikeM.

Comment: post the xml for `R.id.fullscreen`.  You may have to set an onClick element here or create an `onClickListener` in the code if you haven't got this option set.

Comment: In items.xml i have `android:id="@+id/fullscreen"` @COYG

Comment: And where is `R.menu.items` being used? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think that this isn't the problem, the other item works perfectly, just this is creating problems @MikeM.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited! @MikeM.

Comment: Can you confirm that the case is true ? put a breakpoint or a Log to make sure that the code inside `case R.id.fullscreen` is actually reachable.

Comment: Yes, its reachable, I added a `Toast` and it appeared @113408

Comment: Did you try to use 'this' instead of `getBaseContext()` ?

Comment: Same @LevonPetrosyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is this line

```
intent.putExtra(key, bitmap);
```

Android limits size in intent's data. There are 2 cases

- The app will crash with a `RuntimeException`, you can easily see this exception in logcat like below screenshot

[image]

- The app won't crash but showing nothing and back to home screen (your case). Actually there is a warning about this issue, to see the warning you must change logcat type to **Warn** and logcat filter to **No Filters** like below screenshot.

[image: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException]

As you can see the warning like, `812104` in my case, it might be different in your case.

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 812104 bytes
```

**Solutions:** If you need to pass a bitmap from an activity to another

- If the bitmap is a URL (file path, http/https links, etc) or a resource id (R.drawable.splash_screen, etc) then just pass the URL or resource id to another activity.
- If the bitmap comes from a users' action (captured from camera for example) then you can save the bitmap in a local file then pass the file path to another activity.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom toolbar to inflate menu then please set toolbar :-

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

then the menu is inflated properly
**otherwise the problem is not this.**